# I am going through the chainlink functions tutorial and trying to deploy FunctionsConsumer contract and getting an error from undici

Tags: chainlink

I am working through the chainlink functions tutorial and I am attempting to deploy FunctionsConsumer contract to the mumbai testnet and I am getting an error. I am pretty sure that I  have my environment variables MUMBAI_RPC_URL and PRIVATE_KEY set up correctly in the .env.enc file. I do not have any other variables in my .env.enc file. When i run the previous command in the tutorial
`npx hardhat functions-simulate`
I get the intended output. However, when I run the subsequent command `npx hardhat functions-deploy-client --network mumbai --verify false` I get the following error

```
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
Deploying FunctionsConsumer contract to mumbai

__Compiling Contracts__
Nothing to compile
An unexpected error occurred:

ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
    at onConnectTimeout (/Users/oxsnosh/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:182:24)
    at /Users/oxsnosh/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:129:46
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/oxsnosh/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:170:9)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
}
```

I have mumbai MATIC and LINK in the wallet for the PRIVATE_KEY variable.
Please let me know if there is anything I am missing to get this to run correctly.

I know its not the environment variables because I was getting another error before correcting them. At least I'm pretty sure its not the MUMBAI_RPC_URL or PIVATE_KEY.

Edit: I am using a PRIVATE_KEY for the wallet address that was whitelisted for the functions beta

Comment: I figured this out. I used the nvm package to switch node versions to node v 19.9.0. For some reason I believe there is an issue starting at node version 18.6 that will throw that error from undici.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu with Remote Server.
If so try it without it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was using node version 18.6 and needed to use node version 19.0. I switched versions using the nvm package.